# Maven test fails within install phase but is ok within test phase

Tags: testing, maven, integration, integration-testing, ebean

I have an empty java test with Spring and Ebean

```
protected static ApplicationContext ctx;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void initSpringContext() {
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");
    }

public class SomeTest extends SpringBase {

    @Test
    public void emptyTest() {}
}
```

I had a problem with class loading:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: models.Flat is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server?
```

Problem was fixed with pom config

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After this fix "mvn clean test" runs ok, but "mvn clean install" fails with exact exception
I suppose it's because integration-test phase.
I tried to config useSystemClassLoader in maven-failsafe-plugin, run with param -Dskip.integration.test=true but is makes no difference, I have feeling that this plugin did not call at all.

Also I've compared surefire-reports genereted by "mvn clean test" and "mvn clean verify" -- section "properties" within the testsuite is identical in both cases.

Skipping integration-test will be also an acceptable solution.

> Maven 2.2.1 OS - Tested under Windows and Debian

If it can help, stacktrace of error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: models.Flat is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server?
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQuery(DefaultServer.java:1008)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQuery(DefaultServer.java:965)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.find(DefaultServer.java:1001)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.find(Ebean.java:1143)
    at flats.crawler.managers.CrawlerManager.initCrawlerHashes(CrawlerManager.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:132)
    ... 48 more
```

I've run two commands "mvn clean install -X" and "mvn clean test -X" and compared test classpathes:
in first case

```
[DEBUG]   PATH\MODULE\target\MODULE-1.0.jar
```

in second case

```
[DEBUG]   PATH\MODULE\target\classes
```

that's why Ebean can't find classes

Comment: um, failsafe and surefire do not use same test classes, so integration test classes and unit test classes are not the same. Which is this, is it a unit test class or an integration test class? You could also let us know the exception stack trace etc.

Comment: I know that the IT tests and unit tests are different things, I want to make it usual unit test. I have no IT tests in project at all.

Comment: what I meant is that failsafe plugin will bind to *IT.java where as surefire will bind to *Test.java -> you wouldn't have both at the same time, so I don't think this is the issue, if you only have *Test.java tests.
Could you run maven with debug flag on, `mvn -X`, to see if it gives out any new information?

Comment: Added info to the question about mvn -X result, thanks

Comment: Hmm.. Can you elaborate why you think it'd be the reason for ebean to not find the classes? Shouldn't they work equally well with both? There's still lot of missing pieces in the puzzle I think. Why do you have the empty test? why are you extending springbase in the empty test? What's in the spring-context.xml?

Answer (score 0):

For integration tests the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/) is responsible and NOT the maven-surefire plugin. So you configurations to ignore the integration test couldn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure about this=) I can add skipTests=true to the maven-failsafe-plugin config and it will not make differ

Comment: Cause i assumme you didn't correctly configure the maven-failsafe-plugin.

Comment: I suppose failsafe is not needed here at all

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this [FAQ entry](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/class-loading.html) in the failsafe plugin docs?  It gives a whole bunch of options for classloading configuration.

If none of those suggestions work for you, and skipping the integration tests is okay (as you mentioned),  then `-DskipITs=true` should do it, per the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#skipITs).